# Inno Setup Exec doesn't wait for InstallShield uninstallation to complete

Tags: inno-setup, installshield

Trying to uninstall a software using the uninstall string (and running that with `Exec` in `InitializeSetup`) before installation, it doesn't wait for the un-installation to complete but proceeds to the next step of installation in Inno Setup.

I am using the following code and the software I am trying to un-install in an Installshield product:

```pascal
Exec(
  ExpandConstant('{pf}\InstallShield Installation Information\{{XXX8X88X-XX8X-88X8-X8XX-88X888X88888}\setup.exe'),
  '-s -runfromtemp -l0x0004 -removeonly -remove', '',
  SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ReturnCode)
```

Comment: I am using the following code and the software I am trying to un-install in an Installshield product :Exec(ExpandConstant('{pf}\InstallShield Installation Information\{{XXX8X88X-XX8X-88X8-X8XX-88X888X88888}\setup.exe'), '-s -runfromtemp -l0x0004  -removeonly -remove', '', SW_SHOW, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ReturnCode)

Comment: Origiinal installer has registered the same cmd line options which I have written in the query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `setup.exe` most probably executes a subprocess for an actual uninstallation and exits itself. So Inno Setup seemingly does not wait for the process to finish. This is a common behavior, as the uninstaller needs to delete itself, what it cannot do, if it still running. So it creates a copy of itself (or another executable) in a temporary folder and (re)executes from there.

As per [InstallShield documentation](https://docs.revenera.com/installshield24helplib/helplibrary/IHelpSetup_EXECmdLine.htm), you can try adding `/w` or `/Clone_wait` switches to the command-line:

> `/w` ...  For a Basic MSI project, the `/w` option forces `Setup.exe` **to wait until the installation is complete before exiting.**
>
> `/Clone_wait` ... This parameter indicates that the original setup should **wait for the cloned setup process to complete before exiting**.