# Inno setup to sequentially execute other uninstallers (3rd party apps)

Tags: inno-setup

I have search for almost 2 days including going through regular documentation for inno setup.  But I have not found a way for Inno setup to sequentially execute other uninstallers (3rd party apps), as items in the [UninstallRun] section.  Since the other uninstallers are "cloned" the "waituntilterminated" flag doesn't work on those uninstallers.  Has anyone come up with a way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
David

Comment: There's hardly any universal solution for this on the caller (Inno) side. You should check the other installers, if they offer an API to wait for them to completely finish. For example, if those are InstallShield uninstallers, see [Inno Setup Exec doesn't wait for InstallShield uninstallation to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49893227/850848).

Comment: The two in installers I want wait for are also inno setup based.    I wished I could suppress the cloning,  that would then allow me to wait.  I am doing a work around using a command prompt to guide user to to continue after each uninstall is completed.  These uninstalls have to occur in a particular order and the person running them is not an IT person,  but this is wadi was ask to provide.

Comment: @DavidMoore did you ever find a good solution for this? currently looking at the same issue

Answer (score 0):

If the other uninstallers are Inno Setup-made, then I do not think you need to do anything special.

Inno Setup-made uninstaller really clones itself and run its clone internally. But it waits for the clone to actually complete the uninstallation before it closes itself. The only thing, that the clone does after the main uninstaller processes closes, is that it deletes the uninstaller executable (and its data files). I do not think you really need to wait for this to done. But if you do, just wait for the uninstaller files to be gone, before you proceed with the other uninstaller.